# Arranging my applications by type on Ubuntu with GNOME Shell

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell

I'm using the latest Ubuntu 17.10 with the GNOME shell. It's really lovely but I'm still lost and finding my way around Linux for the first time in my life.

Anyone knows how to arrange the applications by type (rather than by name)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer for you may be to enable the "applications menu".  This can be installed in your system in two ways:

Do do this, run the program `tweaks` in the section marked 'Extensions' the second entry should be 'Applications menu'.  If you turn this on, you will have a drop-down menu in the top left corner (Activities) which organizes programs by type.

You can install the package 'gnome-shell-extensions' - this will install a number of handy extensions to your system including 'applications menu'.  This can be installed using the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extensions
```

or it can be installed by using the Software Center

Alternatively, if you do not want a bunch of extra extensions, you can use your web browser to navigate to the website https://extensions.gnome.org and search for the extension 'Applications menu' and install the extension from that website.  Please note that there are more than one application menu available - I have not tested them all.

Comment: I tried this but the second entry under "extensions" reads "ubuntu appindicators"  It is turned on but I don't have any drop-down menu in the top left corner!!??

Comment: @NermeenHussein I did a little more research on my side, and will update my answer about that shortly.

Comment: Ok I ran this command and I think that it installed some things.  But how or where can I find what got installed so I can use it??  Sorry, again for my ignorance!

Comment: @NermeenHussein That's no problem - we're all learning!  The extensions should now be present in the `tweaks` program.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help and patience.  I think it all looks perfect and excellent now.  Couldn't ask for more :-))  Have yrself a great day.

Answer (score 2):

You may use custom app folders to organise your application launchers in the "*All*" section of "*Show Applications*" so that this section looks like this:

[image]

You can do this using a GNOME shell extension called "**Appfolders Management extension**" by clicking on the on/off button [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1217/appfolders-manager/) (you'll have to install a browser add-on/extension suggested by the webpage first).

Once you have installed the extension, you'll be able to right click and send any application launcher to specific app folder(s).

[image]

Alternatively you may use an application called [GNOME App Folders Manager](https://github.com/muflone/gnome-appfolders-manager).

Comment: Ok, I started by installing the browser add-on to be able to download the "appfolders management extension" but I got this message: "Although GNOME Shell integration extension is running, native host connector is not detected. Refer documentation for instructions about installing connector."

Comment: @NermeenHussein You'll have to [install a package](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShellIntegrationForChrome/Installation). You can do this by running `sudo apt-get install chrome-gnome-shell`.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I ran the command but I still don't know how to reach the extension that got installed so I can work with it?

Comment: @NermeenHussein You can manage your installed extensions from the "Extensions" section of (GNOME) Tweaks (if not installed you can install it by `sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool`) or from this webpage: https://extensions.gnome.org/local/.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all your help :-)) my life is much better and organized now.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to switch to one of the following alternatives

- GNOME Classic (`sudo apt-get install gnome-panel`);
- GNOME FlashBack (`sudo apt-get install gnome-flashback`).